# How do you know the random effect in a Linear Mixed Model will improve the fit?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, linear-model

I understand that when fitting a Linear Model you might want to model a random effect which is violating the independent residuals between samples rule.

For example looking at the survival rate of patients 2000 who go to a clinic by looking at the age, height, weight, sex. Another factor will be the doctor that they are visiting. If there are 20 doctors at the clinic for the 2000 patients, some doctors might be inherently bad or good at their jobs and therefore effect the dependent variable (outcome) survival rate.

This is where my understanding breaks down.

The 'parameter' in this case (representing the effect of doctors on the intercept / slope) is randomly generated from a Gaussian distribution?

Why would this random variable help improve the fit of the model? What happens if doctor #1 is especially bad, but the variable drawn from the Gaussian distribution happens to be higher than the mean survival rate. And how does this method of drawing a random variable from a Gaussian distribution help solve the violation of the independence of residuals assumption?

Comment: In terms of goodness of fit, it's a regularization method.  Have you studied ridge regression?

Comment: Another way of looking at it is that it allows for the correlation between patients within doctors which in your example is produced by differences in te skills of the doctors.

Comment: Thanks for the response @mdewey, I understand the concept which you mention. If you read the last paragraph of my question that is where my confusion lies. We are assuming the skill level of doctors is normally distrusted, ok. But how can we FIT this difference in skill levels by drawing from a RANDOM distribution. What happens if doctor #2 is highly skilled but we happen to draw a value below the mean from the random distribution?

Comment: @MatthewDrury I will research this now and get back to you as soon as I have a good understanding. I really like it how you refered to "regularisation methods". The definition for "regularisation method" on wikipedia is: " introducing additional information in order to solve an ill-posed problem". This is where my confusion with LMM lies. The 'additional information' we are introducing is drawn RANDOMLY. Of course the design matrix is not random, but this is being multiplied by a random vector. How can a random vector bring us any closer to fitting our values? (see last paragraph of question)

Comment: They are not random in the sense you suggest.